# How to run Bergman with Lispstick (or Portacle)

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to run the bergman package http://servus.math.su.se/bergman/manual/manual.html#htoc3 in either Lispstick or Portacle. I downloaded both of these programs and installed quicklisp in them. I also already downloaded the "current version packed for Windows". However, the manual of Bergman doesn't really explain how to run it here, it just says

"You can start a bergman session by typing bergman followed by Enter."

(So, for example, I don't even know where I should be typing "bergman"...)

Could someone quickly explain how to do this? (I am using Windows 10)

*Disclaimer*: I am a mathematician trying to do some computations with the bergman package for LISP, so apologies in advanced for my absolute lack of knowledge on all of this.

Comment: Maybe it could suit you better http://maxima.sourceforge.net/documentation.html "Maxima is a computer algebra system comparable to commercial systems like Mathematica and Maple. It emphasizes symbolic mathematical computation: algebra, trigonometry, calculus, and much more."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need Lispstick or Portacle as they ship with the SBCL common lisp implementation , you need to install the CLISP common lisp implementation: https://sourceforge.net/projects/clisp/.

Try follow these steps:

- Unzip the downloaded bergman folder
- In the unzipped bergman folder, navigate to `scripts/clisp/win9598nt/`
- Open a prompt in this folder, hold shift then right click and select `"Open PowerShell window  here"` or alternatively select command prompt if that option is displayed instead.
- Enter the following: `./makebr "path/to/clisp/install"`, substituting `path/to/clisp/install` with the path of the clisp install folder containing the `clisp.exe` executable (in other words the folder you installed CLISP to)
- Wait for the bergman system to build. You can now close the command prompt window.
- Go back to the root of the bergman folder. Navigate to `bin/clisp/win9598nt/` to find the output executable. Just double click `bergman.exe` to start the bergman session.

Note I've never used bergman, I just tried installing it when I saw your question so I'm not sure if these steps are entirely correct but the resulting executable seems to show the same interface as the manual you linked in your question.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks.